# making a method that checks a generic type, then does the relevant null checks

Tags: c#

I have a method that is being used to update a record in a database, it accepts some parameters. This method at the beginning calls another method for getting further information about the record with a different call, based on a passed in ID.

What I am trying to do is (please see below) when the `UpdateTheRecord` method is called, have a second method called `CheckValueOrElseGetProperty` which allows me to pass in an object return type (such as string, int, etc.), a object argument (to find the property value if an if condition is met, such as `string.IsNullOrEmpty`), and a lambda expression to specify the property.

In the `CheckValueOrElseGetProperty` I can use `typeof(T)` to get the type and execute the checks. But I am unsure of how to call a method with the three generic types, and how to specify the property selection expression.

So, for brevity, let's assume that you have the following method:

```
public static void UpdateTheRecord(Guid id) {
   MyObjectType myObject = GetFurtherInformation(id);

   // call generic method to check "property", 
   // pass in type to do checks, pass in MyObjectType and 
   // with a FUNC specify the property to use if the if condition is met
}
```

This is where I have issues:

```
public static T CheckValueOrElseGetProperty<T, TProperty, TReturnType> (Func<T, TProperty> propertySelector) {
     if (typeof(T) is string) {
            // pseudo code
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(T)
     }
}
```

Comment: If you need special cases based on the type you're likely in need of polymorphism, not generics.

Comment: But can't I pass it in via second generic type?

Comment: That's a lot of text and you haven't even told us **what** it is you want to check for. Next time take a moment to format your code as well. Look at the current state and look back at how it looked when you posted it.

Comment: DBNull is a pretty horrible "no idea, let's just add it and make it somebody else's problem" disease.  Trying to make it generic is a "I don't want it either, pass the buck" response.  Doesn't work, the buck stops at your desk.

Comment: I apologize I was being vague. What I am trying to do is to pass in an object, an expression that specifies a property on that object, and a primitive type such as a string. If the string is null, then return the value of the property (specified by the expression) of the object. Since I am unsure of the Type of the primitive described above, I am confused as to how one could pass this in, in a generic fashion, then do a GetType on it to call the relevant checks. (relevant checks being, for example, being string.IsNullOrEmpty(), or maybe comparing against Guid.Empty, etc.)